# how to identify best answer and yet also supply full answer

Tags: discussion, up-votes

Someone answered my question with enough detail so I could forge a full solution.  I want to reward him with best answer, but I also want to display the full solution (source code) and add explanation as to how and why it works.  I don't want the next guy along to have to recreate the work I did.

But how do I do that?  If I answer my own question with the full solution, then that is what someone visiting should look at first.  The only way I know to mark the solution I like best is to give it the best answer check (which I would have to put on my own answer).   How do I reward the guy that helped me get there.  Just a simple up-vote on his answer?

In general, what is the best way for the author of a question to post a "full solution"?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend (if you're capable) editing the answer and adding in the full source code and such. If you do not have enough reputation to do that, then just edit your question to have a note at the bottom saying everything you did with the source code.

Comment: That's a good idea I hadn't thought of.  I hope someone can come up with a good idea for people <3k too